# Кнопка меняет цвет при нажатии JSON

Tags: javascript, css, json, button

Доброе время суток всем . Ребята ,сижу ломаю голову как сделать чтоб нажимаешь на кнопку и она стала зеленого цвета и рядом в диве высветилась (1) ,второй раз нажимаешь и кнопка уже синего цвета ,высвечивается (0) .В интернете находил совсем не то что нужно или кнопка меняла цвет когда зажал , когда отжимаешь то она в исходный цвет возвращается ,а нужно чтоб фиксировано .

Answer (score 2):

Для изучения AJAX рекомендую начать со статей из учебника Кантора: [1 статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) и [2 статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms)

```js
let result = 0;
let myEvent = function() {
  if (result == 0) {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    result++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('my-button').style.backgroundColor = '#47a4ff';
    result--;
  }
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, false); //url по которому будет выполнятся запрос
  let body = 'result=' + result;
  xhr.send(body);
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  } else {
    alert('При отправке данных произошла ошибка');
  }
}
```

```css
#my-button {
  background-color: #47a4ff;
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button" onclick="myEvent()">Жмакни меня!</button>
<div id="result">0</div>
```

Comment: Блин ,Сергей извиняюсь за свою эмоциональность но вы просто Бог ) Я просто помню что в какой-то теме вы тоже меня уже выручали . Спасибо Вам огромное ) А кстати можно это все сделать на JSON  чтоб можно было выводить данные с DB по принципу (нажал на кнопку и записалась единица в базу данных , еще раз нажал и записался ноль )

Comment: Из клиентского JS-файла такое не возможно, для этого надо отправлять запрос на сервер, и сервер уже будет записывать/перезаписывать ваш JSON, для этого надо знать, на чем у вас написан сервер - php, nodeJS, asp.net и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: перепутал , не JSON ,а AJAX чтоб можно было в базу данных (в таблицу) записывать один или ноль при повторном нажатии .

Comment: смотрел примеры с голосованием но наверное из-за того что я далек от темы AJAX особо не понял что к чему (

Comment: Добавил отправку AJAX запроса, вам нужно только подставить свой URL и обратотку на сервере. Если возникнут еще какие-то вопросы, то лучше задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшее ,чтоб я без вас делал )

Comment: Сергей ,я извиняюсь что отвлекаю может вас но не могли бы вы глянуть на эту тему "Запись данных по onClick с помощью AJAX"  я попробовал создать базу данных и подключить но что-то без успешно .(

Comment: Есть какие-то идеи по этому поводу ?

Comment: Сергей ,я пробовал сегодня вставить url но почему-что ничего не записывалось . Сможете глянуть что не так ?

Comment: ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ СЕРГЕЙ . Я ВАС  очень прошу ,можете глянуть эту тему ? "Передавать и принимать данные в формате JSON"

Comment: проблема с  xhr.open('POST', url, false); , я там все верно ввел ,но почему-то ничего не показывает .((

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ НАДЕЮСЬ НА ВАШ ОТКЛИК

Answer (score 1):

На простом js ответили выше. При помощи jquery:

```js
var flag = 0;
$('.bt').click(function() {
  if (flag == 0) {
    $('.bt').css('background', 'green');
    flag++;
  } else {
    $('.bt').css('background', 'blue');
    flag--;
  }
  $('.res').text(flag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="bt">Button</button>
<div class="res">0</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Артем за столь быстрый ответ .

Comment: @technoimpex technoimpex не за что)